# Efficient Datatype Python (list or numpy array?)

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I'm still confused whether to use list or numpy array.
I started with the latter, but since I have to do a lot of append 
I ended up with many vstacks slowing my code down.
Using list would solve this problem, but I also need to delete elements
which again works well with delete on numpy array.

As it looks now I'll have to write my own data type (in a compiled language, and wrap).
I'm just curious if there isn't a way to get the job done using a python type.

To summarize this are the criterions my data type would have to fulfil:

- 2d n (variable) rows, each row k (fixed) elements
- in memory in one piece (would be nice for efficient operating)
- append row (with an in average constant time, like C++ vector just always k elements)
- delete a set of elements (best: inplace, keep free space at the end for later append)
- access element given the row and column index ( O(1) like data[row*k+ column]

It appears generally useful to me to have a data type like this and not impossible to implement in C/Fortran.
What would be the closest I could get with python?
(Or maybe, Do you think it would work to write a python class for the datatype? what performance should I expect in this case?)

Comment: I suspect the problem is not the numpy data structure itself, but rather the use of `vstack`, which always creates a new array rather than resizing an existing array.

Comment: One full stop, two commas, three question marks... it must be a record in syntax boycotting! :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, if you were doing this in C or Fortran, you'd have to have an idea of the size of the array so that you can allocate the correct amount of memory (ignoring `realloc`!). So assuming you do know this, why do you need to append to the array?

In any case, numpy arrays have the `resize` method, which you can use to extend the size of the array.

Comment: In C I would start with eg. an array size of kx1000 and double the allocated memory every time I run out of space (if this doubling copies all the data is ok, as long as it is not copied every single time I add a row). Resize looks interesting. (I was not aware of it before.) I guess I should still rather do the bookkeeping myself and always resize to double the size, rather then resizing for every new row.